# RCLRSC makes SRVPGM with F-spec crash

Tags: ibm-midrange, rpgle

I am the first one to introduce SRVPGM into our application. In my SRVPGM I defined several necessary files globally, since we have around 50k transactions per days and the sub procedures will be called 10s of times per transaction. While these sub procedures are shared used by both batch jobs and inter jobs, to reduce file locking I open the files in relevant sub proc if not opened(with %open), and close the file under INTER job mode before return from sub proc.

Unfortunately our user interface entry program is an OPM with RCLRSC. I found every time I quit the interface and login again, the SRVPGM will hv problem: in the file reading sub proc, the %open returns 1, but when chain/read the file the system prompts "Tried to refer to all or part of an object that no longer exists.". I even tried to remove the checking on %open and directly open(e) the problem still persists.

I have searched several articles discussing the same problem, but still I can't find a preferred solution.

Our existing(>1k) pgms are nearly all *DFTACTGRP.

We have a number of pgms with RCLRSC, that my project budget can't cover the effort to study and remove/replace the RCLRSC.

There a much more number of pgms with OVRDBF/OPNQRYF not specifying open scope, so I can't simply change our pgms to a named ACTGRP.

So what is the next I can consider? Can the below methods solve my problem(I am still testing them now, though)

1. If I just keep files opened till the INTER job ends, since our SRVPGM only read files?
2. If I define 2 sets of file reading sub proc, one with files defined globally for batch job usage, one with files defined locally for INTER jobs?
3. Give up SRVPGM, simply bind the modules to each calling programs(aound 70, still able to manage)?

Answer (score 1):

Using RCLRSC with service programs and ILE procedures is problematic at best. RCLRSC is strictly an OPM tool from the days before activation groups even existed, and on modern machines only affects the default activation group, but it does not completely clean it up or end it. RCLRSC only closes files and ends programs compiled with DFTACTYGRP(*YES). If DFTACTGRP(*NO) is selected, RCLRSC does not touch it.

The next issue is that you can not use sub-procedures in programs compiled with DFTACTGRP(*YES). This is because IBM does not want ILE procedures running in the default activation group. It can be done, but only if you are careful, and RCLRSC will be a problem as you saw. The files are closed, but the ILE program objects do not know about it because the activation group is not ended and cleaned up. In addition, coercing ILE procedures to run in the default activation group by specifying ACTGRP(*CALLER) is discouraged because you can't completely shut down the default activation group without ending the job.

If your OPM code is loaded with RCLRSC commands that you can't remediate, then you will be best off to avoid sub-procedures. But the best way forward is to work on removing the RCLRSC commands.